# Array index not performing as it should?

Tags: php, laravel

I've got the following code and it's driving me insane..

```
echo $this->year; //This echoes 2019
return $set_year[2019]; //This works, it returns the expected value
return $set_year[$this->year]; //This returns nothing and gives me an 'Undefined Index'
```

What's going on here? Here is how I set the array:

```
return [
    'years' => [

        2019 => 7,
        2018 => 8,
        2017 => 9,
        2016 => 10,
        2015 => 11,
        2014 => 12,
        2013 => 13,

    ],

];
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->year);` give you …?

Comment: What does var_dump($this->year); die(); shows?

Comment: [The manual on `return` states](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) and I quote: *"If called from within a function, the return statement **immediately ends execution of the current function**, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return also **ends the execution** of an eval() statement or script file."* - So the 2nd return never happens.

Comment: Now you are driving us crazy :D

Comment: @04FS and @MyLibary are pointing a good point. Maybe the value of $this->year is a string and not a number. PHP arrays can have numeric or string indexes so you may need to cast the value before like this: `return $set_year[(int)$this->year];`

Comment: @PatrickJanser Seems to work for me regardless of int or string https://3v4l.org/EHjKd

Comment: @PatrickJanser that should not make a difference in PHP, unless $this->year is neither string nor integer, perhaps in a date format?

Comment: @xwlee Then how is `return $set_year[2019]` working for OP?

Comment: I agree with @MrEvers. It's quite possible that `$this->year` is some object with the magic method `__toString()` implemented, giving you a nice number when you echo it.

Comment: Numeric vs string does not make a difference to PHP here, casting would happen implicitly. Seeing the var_dump output is important, so we can verify what the property _actually_ contains - it might be something like extra whitespace before or after `2019`, that can hardly be spotted with a normal echo. var_dump shows the _length_ of the value as well, so it helps spot such issues.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I think that was just OP's style of writing to show the issues otherwise it wouldn't have thrown error for 2nd one as control would have never reached there.

Comment: @vivek_23 Yeah, I thought of that after, so you stand being right. I was going to ask them if what they posted was used as shown or separately. I failed to do that, my bad. Thanks for raising that though.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That's fine :)

Comment: Please, edit your question and all full code, it is not visible to us what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked... but I am yet to figure out why

```
$set_year = Config::get('sitevars.years');
return $this->year ? $set_year[$this->year] : 0;
```